# Can I use DisplayPort with the other ports on my video card?

Tags: video, graphics-card, amd-radeon, displayport, eyefinity

I have a [Radeon HD5570](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5570/Pages/hd-5570-overview.aspx)
[image: Picture of video card]

I am planning on using this adapter to place a third VGA monitor in the DisplayPort:
[image: Picture of DisplayPort-to-VGA adapter]

However, before I spend the money on this particular adapter, I need to know if it will do what I need it to do. I need the adapter to provide output to a third monitior, *in addition* to the other monitors plugged into the onboard VGA and DVI ports.

Will this provide the triple-monitor functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the "Specifications" tab of your link, it states:

- ATI Eyefinity multi-display technology [1,17]

  - Three independent display controllers
    Drive three displays simultaneously with independent resolutions, refresh rates, color controls, and video overlays

So, yes. You may do that. Your adapter, if it is mini-Displayport to VGA (as I believe it is) should be fine. It's important to note that AMD uses **mini**-DisplayPort, not standard DisplayPort. So be sure that is what it is.

Comment: It's funny that you would say that about the mini-DisplayPort, because I physically have the card in front of me, and it is most definitely a full-size DisplayPort. Larger images of the card will confirm this as well. I Have found AMD/ATI cards in both categories - mini-DisplayPort and full-size DisplayPort. I guess they just like to mix it up. :) Also, the adapter is a full-size DisplayPort plug as well.

Comment: @Giffyguy I have not seen that. Perhaps it's on cards that are geared towards more than 3 outputs. Mine has 5 outputs (2 DVI, 1 HDMI, and 2 mini-DP). Good to note. :)

Comment: Display port is "just another connector" on your card. We leased desktops at work with DP ports so that we'd only need a $30 adapter to connect a second monitor to the systems. There have been some power management issues we've had to deal with, but they're minor compared with the cost and complexity savings compared to dealing with discrete video cards for multi-monitor setups.